# Need to open the datepicker popup on click of the calendar icon instead of clicking on the input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

my below datepicker code is like below. Its working fine. But the datepicker popup opens when i click on the input field. But  want that to be open once i click on the calendar icon. Please suggest me a way to achieve that.

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 padleft">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1">Start Date
        </label>
        <div class="input-group" style="width:75%">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="text" 
        class="form-control date" 
        id="dateFrom" 
        placeholder="From" 
        ng-click="model.dateFrom=true"
        datepicker-popup="{{model.format}}" 
        ng-model="model.defect.startDate" 
        is-open="model.dateFrom" 
        datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
        date-disabled="model.disabled(date, mode)" 
        ng-required="true" 
        close-text="Close"  my-date>
          <span class="btn btn-default " ng-click="model.dateFrom=true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In My controller :

```
     self.format = 'MM-dd-yyyy';
     self.open = function($event) {

        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        self.opened = {};
        self.opened[$event.target.id] = true;

        // log this to check if its setting the log    
        console.log(self.opened);

      };
```

Angular : 1.6
Using 'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker',
and    'ui.bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add `ng-click="model.dateFrom=true"` as an attribute to the `<i>` element containing your calendar icon, not its parent span.

I would actually recommend writing a separate function for toggling the datepicker on and off. Something like

```
$scope.toggleDatePicker = function() {
    $scope.model.dateFrom = !$scope.model.dateFrom;
};
```

and then calling that from your html: `ng-click="toggleDatePicker()"`

Comment: Thanks arykay i ll try and reply you

Comment: No buddy, its not working the way you suggested. Any other idea?